# Type '{ userId: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'AxiosRequestConfig'. | Axios - Next.js with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

( Hi comunnity ) I have this piece of code, everything was working fine, but got an error once i create the API.delete function, don't know what is going on there actually

```
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig } from "axios";

const API = axios.create({ baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/api" });

// Set header for each request to give permission

API.interceptors.request.use((req: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
  if (localStorage.getItem("Auth")) {
    req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Auth")).token
    }`;
  }
  return req;
});

// login - register - update perfil

export const login = (loginData: {
  email: string | null;
  password: string | null;
}) => API.post(`/user/login`, loginData);

export const register = (registerData: {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  name: string;
}) => API.post("/user/register", registerData);

export const updatePerfilPhotos = (
  photosBase64: { perfil?: string; banner?: string },
  id: string
) => API.patch(`/user/update/${id}`, photosBase64);

export const AddNotification = (
  userInformation: { userId: string },
  id: string
) => API.patch(`/user/notification/${id}`, userInformation);

export const DeleteNotificationOrFriend = (
  userInformation: { userId: string },
  id: string
) => API.delete(`/user/deleteNotification/${id}`, userInformation);

//
```

In the API.delete function there's a problem :

```
(parameter) userInformation: {
    userId: string;
}
Type '{ userId: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'AxiosRequestConfig'
```

**What does that mean ?** why is that happening, how can i fix this ?

Thanks for your time friends !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `delete` method signature should be like this,

```
API.delete(`/user/deleteNotification/${id}`, { data: userInformation })
```

Refer: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/897#issuecomment-343715381

Comment: Yes sir, you're right, i didn't know that, thanks !!